# Where stands the observer with respect to the opengl coordinate system?

Tags: opengl, glut

I understand the opengl coordinate system and moving around it with glTranslatef and drawing within it with glVertex3f procedures.
What is however unclear to me is how does it relate to the arguments gluPerspective takes. I mean zNear and zFar. They are relative to the observer, but where stands he from the opengl coordinates' (0,0,0) point?

Comment: I would suggest you start with modern OpenGL. [This tutorial](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/) also covers 3D maths and coordinate systems.

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere. OpenGL does not have an "observer" or a "camera". It's all just about transforming coordinates around. Modelview to Eye Space. Eye Space to Clip Space. Clip Space to Normalized Device Coordinates to Viewport.